# jQuery Turning off preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, preventdefault

I have a page where I have a 'get directions button'. The href of the tag is # so that it is self linked. When the user clicks this button, I have a script the prevents the default behavior if the link is still set to '#'. It then uses some info from the url to put together an ajax request to my database to get the address of the company whose page you are viewing.  It then uses geolocation to grab the position of the user and then uses that to replace the href attribute of the button.

I had it working completely when the function ran on document.ready, but the browser would ask for permission to get the location before the button was clicked, which was undesirable, so I bound it to the click event.

I call trigger (click) at the end of everything but it is still preventing the default. When I click a button the second time, it does what it is supposed to, but my trigger does not work. My question is: is there a way to make it so once the function runs, the trigger (click) actually works like it was clicked a second time.  My code is below:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="medium-11 medium-centered columns text-center">
            <hr />
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="get-directions button" style="border-radius: 10px; font-family: oswald, sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 14PT;">VIEW MAP & GET DIRECTIONS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    $('.get-directions').click(function(event) {

        console.log($(this).attr("href"));

        var linkHREF = $(this).attr("href");

        console.log(linkHREF);

        if (linkHREF == "#") 
        {
            console.log("PREVENTED");
            event.preventDefault();
        

        var clientPID = window.location.href;
        clientPID = clientPID.match(/\/webapp\/p\/[0-9]+/);
        clientPID = clientPID[0].replace("/webapp/p/", "");
        postData = {"pageID": clientPID};
        var startingLocation;
        var destination;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            data: postData,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dealerLocator/getDirectionsButton.php",
            success: compileAddress
        });

       }//END IF PREVENT
       function compileAddress(jsonData)
        {
            destination = jsonData;
            destination = destination.replace("#", "");
            // check if browser supports geolocation
            if (navigator.geolocation) { 
              if (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition){
              // get user's current position
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {   
                // get latitude and longitude
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                startingLocation = latitude + "," + longitude;

                // send starting location and destination to goToGoogleMaps function
                goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination);
              });
              } 
            } 
        } 
        // go to Google Maps function - takes a starting location and destination and sends the query to Google Maps
        function goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination) {
            $getDirectionsLink = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + startingLocation + "&daddr=" + destination;
            $(".get-directions").attr("href", $getDirectionsLink);

            console.log($(".get-directions").attr("href"));
            $(".get-directions").trigger("click");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand everything here, but try with `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#"`. This way, you should not have to prevent the default behavior in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Just `return false` when you want to disable the default event.